# How to Skip particular join from multiple joins in LINQ based external condition

Tags: linq-to-sql, conditional-statements

### Table A,
Table B,
Table C

If the selected screen is `A` then Join all three tables.
If the selected screen is `B` then do join on `B & C` tables.
is it possible to handle the above scenario with a `single LINQ query` instead of writing `multiple LINQ queries` based on screen selection?

Example :

```
from a in A
           join b in B on new {} equals new {} join c in C on new {} equals to new {} select{a,b,c}
```

Comment: Switch statement and handle it scenario there?

Comment: What type do you expect in the result? If you don't join A table, how would the result have an `a` property? Set it to `null`? Does the join of C table only depend on B table fields? You'll need to use fluent/lambda query syntax to make this easy.

Comment: Thinking further, I think you will still need an if to choose two paths.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič: Then each switch statement needs a separate query. is it possible to handle it with a single query?

Comment: @ChandanKumarSingh I don't think so... Even so: switch statement makes the code more readable.